# PHPExcel - Render HTML markups on output

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpexcel

In my site I have several forms using CKEditor to store it's data. So when I export all the content, in excel I can see 
 markups all over my document. Is there an easy way to convert those to \n or somehow have PHPExcel recognize them as breaks?

I also tried changing the export type to Excel2007 thinking that maybe Excel could just simply render the HTML markup, however when I switch types my report just crashes. So im sticking with Excel5.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
/** PHPExcel */  
require_once '/Excelphp/Classes/PHPExcel.php';  

// Create new PHPExcel object  
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  
$rows=2;
$sheet=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); 

// Set properties  
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")  
->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")  
->setCategory("Test result file");  

//This is the hard coded *non dynamic* cell formatting
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);  
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);  
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(50);  
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(50);  
    $sheet->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(90);
    $sheet->getStyle('A:D') ->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);

//Font Setting for the Support group title.
$Support_team = array('font'=> array('bold'=> true,'color' => array('rgb' => '4D4D4D'),'size'  => 22,'name'  => 'Arial'),'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER),);

//Font settings for the header cells only.
$headers = array('font'=> array('bold'=> true,'color' => array('rgb' => '4D4D4D'),'size'  => 12,'name'  => 'Arial'),'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER),);

//Border settings
$borders = array('borders' => array('inside'=> array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => '717171')),'outline' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => '717171'))));

//  SQl database connections
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "IMC_COE2", "IMC123");  
    mysql_select_db("IMC_COE2",$db);  

    $sql="select client, team_name,support_team_prime,prime_comments,support_team_backup,backup_comments,escalation1,escalation1_comments,escalation2,escalation2_comments,escalation3,escalation3_comments,escalation4,escalation4_comments,note from tbl_address ORDER BY team_name";  
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);  
        if ($numrows>0)  
        {  
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
//Cell Merging 
$sheet
    ->mergeCells('B'.$rows.':D'.$rows)  
    ->mergeCells('B'.($rows+2).':D'.($rows+2))  
    ->mergeCells('B'.($rows+5).':D'.($rows+5))  
    ->mergeCells('B'.($rows+10).':D'.($rows+10))  
    ->mergeCells('C'.($rows+1).':D'.($rows+1))
    ->mergeCells('B'.($rows+11).':D'.($rows+11)); 

// Add some data  
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)  
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+1), 'Client:')
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+2), 'Support group contacts')     
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+3), 'Prime:')
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+4), 'Backup:')
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+5), 'Escalations') 
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+6), 'Escalation 1:') 
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+7), 'Escalation 2:') 
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+8), 'Escalation 3:') 
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+9), 'Escalation 4:') 
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+10), 'Notes'); 

//Format the hardcoded text 
$sheet->getStyle('B'.$rows)->applyFromArray($Support_team);
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+2))->applyFromArray($headers);      
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+5))->applyFromArray($headers);  
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+10))->applyFromArray($headers); 

//Row height adjustments
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+3)->setRowHeight(60);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+4)->setRowHeight(60);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+6)->setRowHeight(60);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+7)->setRowHeight(60);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+8)->setRowHeight(60);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+9)->setRowHeight(60);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rows+11)->setRowHeight(100);   


//Cell Wraptext
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+1).':D'.($rows+1))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+3).':D'.($rows+3))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+4).':D'.($rows+4))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+6).':D'.($rows+6))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+7).':D'.($rows+7))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+8).':D'.($rows+8))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('C'.($rows+9).':D'.($rows+9))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+11).':D'.($rows+11))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

//Background color on cells 
$sheet->getStyle('B'.$rows.':D'.$rows)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+2).':D'.($rows+2))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+5).':D'.($rows+5))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+10).':D'.($rows+10))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+1))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+3))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+4))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+6))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+7))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+8))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
$sheet->getStyle('B'.($rows+9))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');         

//Border range  
$sheet->getStyle('B'.$rows.':D'.($rows+11))->applyFromArray($borders);          

//This section is the actual data imported from the SQL database *don't touch*
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)              
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+1), utf8_encode($data['client'])) //this will give cell C2. 
    ->setCellValue('B'.$rows, utf8_encode($data['team_name'])) // this will give cell B2 
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+3), utf8_encode($data['support_team_prime'])) //this will give C5 
    ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+3), utf8_encode($data['prime_comments']))  // This will give D5
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+4), utf8_encode($data['support_team_backup']))  //This will give C6
    ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+4), utf8_encode($data['backup_comments'])) //This will give D6  
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+6), utf8_encode($data['escalation1']))//THis will give you C8
    ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+6), utf8_encode($data['escalation1_comments']))//This will give you D8
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+7), utf8_encode($data['escalation2']))//This will give you C9
    ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+7), utf8_encode($data['escalation2_comments']))//This will give you D9
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+8), utf8_encode($data['escalation3']))//This will give you C10
    ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+8), utf8_encode($data['escalation3_comments']))//This will give you D10
    ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+9), utf8_encode($data['escalation4']))//This will give you C11
    ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+9), utf8_encode($data['escalation4_comments']))//This will give you D11
    ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+11), utf8_encode($data['note'])); //This will give you B13

$rows+=14; 
            }  
        }          

// Rename sheet  
$sheet->setTitle('Directory Tool Full dump');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5) 
ob_end_clean(); 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
$today=date("F.d.Y");
$filename = "Directory_Export-$today.xls";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$objWriter->save('php://output');  
exit;  
?>
```

Comment: MS Excel has no concept of HTML Markup within a cell, it's simply a string value

Comment: `str_replace('<br>', "\n", $str)`?

Comment: @MarcB or `preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Excel has no concept of HTML Markup within a cell, it's simply a string value.... storing a value like `ABC<br />DEF` will simply be treated as a string containing `ABC<br />DEF` and not as two lines containing `ABC` and `DEF` respectively. If you want it to be treated as two lines then you need to change the `<br />` to `"\n"`. You also need to set the cell alignment to wrap.

Comment: +1 I'd suggest the usage of [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) after following your suggestion to get rid of any HTML that Excel can't meaningfully render

Comment: I tried the following and it's replacing the <br /> with \n correctly but Excel is not recognizing it as a break line. It's instead just adding the text \n   $data = str_replace("<br />", '\n', $data);

Comment: PHP 101 - `'\n'` !== `"\n"`.... one is a The first is a literal `\ ` character followed by the letter `n`; the second is a newline character. Single quotes and double quotes make a big difference: [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark, the quotes made the difference. Still a beginner in PHP and learning alot this week with PHPexcel. Everything is working A1! thanks again for all your help.